# How to make a command line executable an application?

Tags: terminal, applications, command-line

I have a command line executable (specifically `JMeter`), which opens a GUI application when launched from the terminal.  However, I would like to create a link to it that would wrap it up to become a proper Mac application (included in `/Applications` directory and all that).  How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

Use Automator.

1. Open Automator and double-click on Application.
2. In the "Name" search box, type Apple and you should see "Run AppleScript".
3. Drag "Run AppleScript" into the right-hand window.
4. Where it says `(* Your script goes here *)`, replace that text with the following code:

   ```
   tell application "Terminal"
       activate
       do script with command "JMeter"
   end tell
   ```
5. File > Save and enter a name, and choose where to save the application.
6. Double-click on the newly created application.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:

```
do shell script "/your/script/path/shellscript.sh"
```

Use this snippet in an AppleScript, then save it as an application.

Answer (score 3):

The [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99437/237) that uses Automator worked for me to wrap GNumeric, but it was opening an ugly Terminal box and I could not close it without closing GNumeric, so I was able to get rid of it by changing it as follows:

```
tell application "/usr/local/bin/gnumeric"
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me, thanks! I used it to create an app for git-cola in a different way than the [original approach](https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola?tab=readme-ov-file#git-colaapp)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the commands to create a minimum version of the app which runs `top` command:

```
APP=Foo
mkdir -vp ${APP}.app/Contents/MacOS ${APP}.app/Contents/Resources # Create the folders.
PATH="$PATH:/usr/libexec" # Make sure PlistBuddy is in the PATH.
printf '#!/usr/bin/osascript\ntell application "Terminal"\n\tactivate\n\tdo script "top"\nend tell\n' > ${APP}.app/Contents/MacOS/${APP}
chmod +x ${APP}.app/Contents/MacOS/${APP} # Sets the executable flag.
PlistBuddy ${APP}.app/Contents/Info.plist -c "add CFBundleDisplayName string ${APP}"
PlistBuddy ${APP}.app/Contents/version.plist -c "add ProjectName string ${APP}"
find ${APP}.app # Verify the files.
open ${APP}.app # Run the app.
```

<sup>Note: The above commands should be executed in shell e.g. in *Terminal*.</sup>

In above code, you can replace `top` with your shell command.

---

In case, you're dealing with Windows apps, consider using [*WineBottler* app](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/).