# How to package a command line software to an Application

Tags: terminal, applications, command-line, development

I have a command line executable (written in C) with some related resources, and I would like to package it as an application (inside the .app folder). I tried `appify.sh` which could package shell script, but didn't work here. For this command line executable, I would like to open termial to show the STDOUT.

I also found [this method using Automator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99435/how-to-make-a-command-line-executable-an-application) , but didn't find how to package the executable and resources inside the folder. Should I write an Info.plist file? I tried but failed to get the right syntax.

### update

As I tested, you cannot run the executable alone, as MacOS will run that without any pop-up window(Termial), and ignore all STDOUT.

We can use Platypus to run sh/bash with `-exec executable` to do the trick as [described here](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus/issues/47).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to make the app and then add your resources.

Comment: Hi, I have tried that, but it seems that it only supports scripts but not binaries. If I replace the generated binary with my executable file, it won't work any more.

Comment: @leetom, use your executable as the script in Resources. If that doesn't work, use a script that execs your executable.

Comment: That works, thank you! I tried that but with wrong work directory and it turns out Resources folder is the default work directory.  I found this solution with `/bin/bash -exe binary` [here](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus/issues/47).