# How to create an app from a .command file?

Tags: applications, script

I have a *MyMacVim.command* file with this content:

```
source ~/.zshrc
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim
```

Is it possible to create an app, say *MyMacVim.app*, from *MyMacVim.command* that I can place in my **Application** folder and use it as an ordinary app? If so, how?

Comment: The answer to your actual question is here: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/Troubleshooting#for-zsh-users

Answer (score -1):

[This similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99435/how-to-make-a-command-line-executable-an-application/99437#99437) has [an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99437/100302) that should work, which is to use Automator to wrap your command up in an app bundle.

Another option which allows for more flexibility (drag and drop, custom icon, URI handlers...) is [Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

Comment: If a question can be answered by an answer in another question you should not lkink to the other question but rather vote to close the new question as a duplicate